# My Xbox 360 wont save GTA 5 games?

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

Originally, I had an issue with my Xbox where it wouldn't start, it would just crash. I was advised to completely uninstall and reinstall, so now it seems to load, but I can't save games - every time I start GTA5 I have to start from the beginning.

How do I get it to save?

Comment: and now it will not even load up

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade! Just to clarify a few questions: is it only GTA 5 that doesn't save? Is your hard drive full? Was there a particular error you were getting when your Xbox crashed? Who told you to uninstall and reinstall (i.e. was it here on Arqade, can you link us??) also, install what exactly? GTA5?